# Run time error 1004 when trying to sort data on three different values

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2010, vba

I've read at least fifteen different articles on this and tried a number of different possible solutions. I am trying to use the VBA code below to sort a worksheet of variable size by three different levels.

When I step through the code I get an error 1004 at the .apply argument of the sort.

**Run-time error '1004':**

**The sort reference is not vald. Make sure that it's within the data you
want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.**

Can anyone suggest a reason why or a solution to this problem?

```
Sub Subbing()

Dim LastCell as String

Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select

LastCell = Selection.Offset(0, 13).Address
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange Range("A2", LastCell)
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R2"), _ SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S2"), _ SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2"), _ SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

End With
End Sub
```

I look forward to your responses. I know this is a common question but I have tried all of the widely suggested methods of resolving my issue and to no avail.

Kind Regards

Pete

Comment: Try recording a macro and compare the resulting code with yours

Comment: My code began its life as a recorded macro and has been edited according to what I have read on various forums about how to solve this issue.Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you selected A:N to sort, but are sorting on the values of R and S as well as D.  Run it through Step mode and put a watch on LastCell - if I'm right, that won't be far enough over for you to actually sort what you want.

Comment: Thanks Joe, me being a doofus and I knew it would be. When I first created the code the data to be sorted contained a lot more columns. I obviously forgot to adjust the sort keys after I had removed the irrelevant information and it should have been to column M not column N. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

... Your criteria range is outside of the sort area - You can't do this.

What I mean is that your sort range will be between Column A and Column N (13 columns after A), but your criteria are in Columns R & S.

If you extend your sort range, all will work.

Hope this fixes everything.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John, you were spot on. Joe just beat you to it though.

Comment: No problem and that's the way it should be - Glad you got it working!!