# Unable to Sort XLS data using Range.Sort

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a xl file with about 2000 rows and columns from A to H. I was trying to sort the file based on the column D such that all other columns are also sorted accordingly (expand selection area).

I am very new to Macros and have been doing this small task to save some time on my reporting.

Here's what I tried:

1. Prompt the user to select a file
2. Set the columns from A to H
3. Sort Range as D2
4. Save the file

As I said, I am new, I have used much of the code from sample examples in the MSDN library. Apart from Sort(), every thing else is working for me.

here's the code

```
Sub Select_File_Windows()
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim FnameInLoop As String
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim SHEETNAME As String

    'Default Sheet Name
    SHEETNAME = "Sheet1"

    ' Save the current directory.
    SaveDriveDir = CurDir

    ' Set the path to the folder that you want to open.
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    ' Open GetOpenFilename with the file filters.
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
            FileFilter:="XLS Files (*.xls),*.xls,XLSX Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", _
            Title:="Select a file", _
            MultiSelect:=True)

    ' Perform some action with the files you selected.
    If IsArray(Fname) Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With

        For N = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)

            ' Get only the file name and test to see if it is open.
            FnameInLoop = Right(Fname(N), Len(Fname(N)) - InStrRev(Fname(N), Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
            If bIsBookOpen(FnameInLoop) = False Then

                Set mybook = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(Fname(N))
                On Error GoTo 0

                DoEvents

                If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "You opened this file : " & Fname(N) & vbNewLine

                    With mybook.Sheets(SHEETNAME)

                        'Columns("A:H").Sort Key1:=Range("D2:D2000"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                        'Range("A1:H2000").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending
                        Columns("A:H").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

                    End With

                    Debug.Print "Sorter Called"

                    mybook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "We skipped this file : " & Fname(N) & " because it is already open. Please close the data file and try again"
        End If
        Next N
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub


Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Nothing is working for me. The file stays as is and No update is made to it. I could not understand, what is the newbie mistake I have been making here ?

Please help.

References:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646(v=office.15).aspx
2. http://analysistabs.com/vba/sort-data-ascending-order-excel-example-macro-code/
3. [Run time error 1004 when trying to sort data on three different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026539/run-time-error-1004-when-trying-to-sort-data-on-three-different-values)

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add a dot in front of `Column` inside With `mybook.Sheets(SHEETNAME)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be as simple as adding a couple of dots (see  pentultimate line below)

```
With mybook.Sheets(SHEETNAME)
    'Columns("A:H").Sort Key1:=Range("D2:D2000"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
       'Range("A1:H2000").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending
       .Columns("A:H").Sort Key1:=.Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: that was it. the (.) fixed it. I remember doing that as well, but it did not work. Looking now at the code versioning, the mistake I made was not using the `With`. Thanks SJR!

Answer (score 1):

SJR is correct in saying that your references should be fully qualified inside of the `With Statement`.

You should simplify your subroutines by extracting large blocks of code into separate subroutines.  The fewer tasks that a subroutines handles, the easier it is to read and to debug.

### Refactored Code

```
Sub Select_File_Windows()
    Const SHEETNAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim arExcelFiles
    Dim x As Long

    arExcelFiles = getExcelFileArray

    If UBound(arExcelFiles) = -1 Then
        Debug.Print "No Files Selected"
    Else
        ToggleEvents False
        For x = LBound(arExcelFiles) To UBound(arExcelFiles)
            If IsWorkbookOpen(arExcelFiles(x)) Then
                Debug.Print "File Skipped: "; arExcelFiles(x)
            Else
                Debug.Print "File Sorted: "; arExcelFiles(x)
                With Workbooks.Open(arExcelFiles(x))
                    With .Sheets(SHEETNAME)
                        .Columns("A:H").Sort Key1:=.Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                    End With
                    .Close SaveChanges:=True
                End With
            End If

        Next

        ToggleEvents True
    End If

End Sub

Function IsWorkbookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsWorkbookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function

Function getExcelFileArray()
    Dim result
    result = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
             FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", _
             Title:="Select a file", _
             MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(result) Then
        getExcelFileArray = result
    Else
        getExcelFileArray = Array()
    End If
End Function

Sub ToggleEvents(EnableEvents As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = EnableEvents
        .Calculation = IIf(EnableEvents, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .EnableEvents = EnableEvents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for the rework. The `IsWorkbookOpen(arExcelFiles(x))` was throwing a compiler error (bad variable type ref). I fixed it and now my code is better than before. Cheers!